# Parse Error : There is a problem_ parsing the package(after signing the Android application)

Tags: android, parsing, signing

I am getting the Parse error after downloading and while installing the apk file of my app on Android phones.

- Before signing the app works fine on device.

  Signing done from Eclipse Export wizard

  Unknown Sources is checked in Settings >Security

Could you please suggest a possible solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys whoever is reading this post.....

I have solved this problem by re installing Eclipse and the SDK, ADT plugin etc.

My eclipse had some low memory issue and removing and reinstalling worked for me :)